# How can I save model data to different tables than that of the View?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to make a simple shopping cart app in Asp.Net Core 2.0 MVC. I'm not doing any Ajax-ing. I have three models:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Cart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CartItemId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; } // not in use yet
}

public class CartItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int NumEach { get; set; } // not in use yet
}
```

From either one of the two views below, I want to update Cart and CartItem, and then get redirected back to the view where I clicked the Add to cart-button:

1) Index-view:

```
@model IEnumerable<simpleShop.Models.Product>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Info)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Info)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</td>
                <td>
                    <form asp-action="AddToCart">
                        <button type="submit" value="@item.Id">Add to cart</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

2) Details-view:

```
@model simpleShop.Models.Product
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title);
}
<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)</h2>
<h4>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Info)</h4>
<h1>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)</h1>
<form asp-action="AddToCart">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" /> 
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
    </p>
</form>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Return to list</a>
</div>
```

Below is my faulty AddToCart-method in the home controller, which at the moment certainly isn't doing anything to save data to the Cart or CartItem tables. How can I get it to?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddToCart([Bind("Id")] Product product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(product);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        if (product.Id > 0) // added to cart via the details-view
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Home", product.Id);
        }
        else // added to cart via the index-view
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
    return View(product);
}
```

Comment: So what is exactly happening currently? Is it getting into the AddToCart action? Have you run it in debug to check the flow?

Comment: The AddToCart action is being run, but it doesn'r receive any data. But as it is now, it's set up to write to the Product table, and not the Cart and CartItem tables. If I change the action method to say CartItem instead of Product, it will just save 0 for NumEach and 0 for ProductId to the CartItem table, and redirect to Home/Details without Id, causing a 404. Which is strange, because of the if-test if product.Id (or cartItem.ID, if I change it, it doesn't matter) is > 0, then redirect to Home/Details + Id, it shound have an Id > 0 ...

Answer (score 0):

for one thing Bind() requires way more than just "id", remember what ever you wanted to bind has to include all properties in question of the object you wanted to pass to new action.

reference comments in line -->>

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddToCart([Bind("Id")] Product product)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       _context.Add(product); //**BAD this will probably try to
                              // add product to the product table again.**
                              // With error to follow about already exists
                              // exception at the SaveChangesAsync call.
       await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

       if (product.Id > 0) 
       {
           return RedirectToAction("Details", "Home", product.Id);
       }
       else // added to cart via the index-view
       {
           return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
       }
    }
    return View(product);
}
```

My suggestion goes along these lines where you will have ProductId and Qty of the Product (your NumEach)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public asyync Task<IActionResult> AddToCart([Bind("ProductId", "NumEach", "CartId")] CartItem model, string ReturnUrl){
    if(ModelState.IsValid){

       _context.CartItem.Add(model);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        //model.Id greater than 0 indicates a save occurred.
        if(model.Id > 0)
          return RedirectToAction(ReturnUrl);  // forced return for further shopping?
        else
          return RedirectToAction("Index");      
    }

     //this assumes bad model state with no error unless model is 
     //annotated accordingly.

    return View(model);
}
```

problem with Cart though is right now you can only store 1 item...

```
public class Cart{
   public Cart(){}


   public int Id {get;set;}   //cart's integer id

   public List<CartItem> CartItems {get;set;} //collection of cartitems

   //FK
   public int CustomerId {get;set;}   //customer's id
   //NAV
   public Customer CustomerId {get;set;}  //customer nav
   ...
}

public class CartItem{
   public CartItem(){}

   public int Id {get;set;}         //cart item id

   public int ProductId {get;set;}   //productid
   public Product Product {get;set;} //nav property

   public int NumEach {get;set;}     //quantity of each product

   //FK
   public int CartId {get;set;}      //Foreign Key
   //NAV
   public Cart Cart {get;set;}       //nav property
}
```

One other thing your index view wouldn't just have the model be a collection of Products it would probably be a viewmdodel that had a collection of products in it but it would also contain the cartid that would have been generated with the visitor.  That CartId would follow that visitor until the transaction was completed and you then have an OrderId or it dies once the session is closed.

```
@model simpleShop.Models.IndexViewModel

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Info)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Info)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</td>
                <td>
                    <form asp-action="AddToCart">
                        <input type="Hidden" asp-for="@Model.CartId" />

                        <button type="submit" value="@item.Id">Add to cart</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>


public class IndexViewModel 
{  
     public IndexViewModel(){}

     public int CartId{get;set;}
     public List<Product> Products{get;set;}
 }
```

I think you get the idea from there.